# How do i configure a label and image according to a date range?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

How do i configure a label and image according to a date range?

Let's say I have an image file name (Aquarius) and I want such that when the user picks a date in the date picker that falls between say **January 21** to **February 12**, the image view displays the Aquarius image and the Label show the name of the image?

so far this is what I have but don't know how to go about it

```
@IBAction func birthDay(sender: AnyObject) {
  let date = datePicker.date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `date1` and `date2` - your limit dates. And you have `UIImageView` named `imageView`.

```
@IBAction func birthDay( sender: AnyObject) {   
  let date = datePicker.date
  if date1.compare(date) == date2.compare(date) { // date between date1 and date2
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Aqurius")
  } else {
    imageView.image = nil // otherwise clear imageView
  }
}
```

To simplify such task you can create extension for NSDate that contain all needed methods.

```
extension NSDate {
    convenience init(dateString:String) {
      let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
      dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
      dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
      let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
      self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d)
    }

    func isDateBetween(date1: NSDate, date2: NSDate) -> Bool {
      return date1.compare(self) == date2.compare(self)
    }
 }
```

And now you can simplify `datePicker`'s method to this:

```
@IBAction func birthDay( sender: AnyObject) {   
  let date = datePicker.date
  if date.isDateBetween(NSDate("2015-06-05"), date2: NSDate("2015-07-05")) { // date between date1 and date2
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Aqurius")
  } else {
    imageView.image = nil // otherwise clear imageView
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, if you want to choose from couple images you can try this:

```
let dates: [(NSDate, NSDate, String)] = [(NSDate("2015-06-05"), NSDate("2015-07-05"), "imgname1"), (NSDate("2015-08-05"), NSDate("2015-08-05"), "imgname2")] // and so on
let date = datePicker.date
for tuple in dates {
  if date.isDateBetween(tuple.0, date2: tuple.1) {
    let imageName = tuple.2
    // do whatever you need
    brea
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver. In  case where i have 11 more images, how can implement that? switch?

Comment: @T-bone, yeah, you are right. Better solution would be switch between dates. Or, you can create Array of type [date1: NSDate, date2: NSDate, imgName: String], where dates are sorted descendant. And when you get date from datePicker, you can loop through array in sort manner: take object at middle, compare to given date, and then decide in witch way go then - left or right.

Comment: I know that I may be asking too much but can you show an example of this switch statement? let's say if date picked is between January 20 thru February 18, imageView show image(aquarius)  or  Feb 19 thru March 20, show image(cancer)

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *)getStarString:(NSDate *)birth
{
    if (![birth isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    df.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";

    NSArray *arr=[[df stringFromDate:birth] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    int m=[arr[1] intValue];
    int d=[arr[2] intValue];

    NSArray *astroArray=@[@"Capricorn",@"Aquarius",@"Pisces",@"Aries",@"Taurus",@"Gemini",@"Cancer",@"Leo",@"Virgo",@"Libra",@"Scorpio",@"Sagittarius",@"Capricorn"];
    NSString *astroFormat = @"102123444543";

    if (m<1||m>12||d<1||d>31){
        return nil;
    }

    if(m==2 && d>29)
    {
        return nil;
    }else if(m==4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11) {

        if (d>30) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    NSInteger index=m-(d < [[astroFormat substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((m-1), 1)] intValue] - (-19));
    return astroArray[index];
}
```

Comment: it's objective-c code ,this function can  help you get the star ,